# Timer circuit activated by the ignition of a car

Tags: timer

I need to create a timer system with the following characteristics:

The system receives a post-key input signal `(12v)` from the ignition of a car. When this input signal is recognized the system activates an output and sends `(12v)`. If the post-key input signal `(12v)` is switched off `(0v)` the output remains on at `(12v)` for 10 minutes. If after 10 minutes the input remains off `(0v)` the system deactivates the output (sends 0v to output). Each time the input is activated `(12v)` and then deactivated `(0v)` the system should start counting up to 10 minutes and then turn off the output. If during the countdown the input is activated again the count must stop and wait until the input is deactivated and then start counting again.

I must do this without the use of microcontroller. I have to use integrated circuit timer, does anyone know of any circuit that can help me do that?

Comment: 555 in monostable config will do.

Comment: Why must you do it without a microcontroller? That's would most of us would use nowadays.

Comment: I am limited in design time and cost. And the number of boards that are produced does not make up for the cost of a project using microcontroller

Comment: 555 will probably not do, for a reasonably accurate 10 minute delay.

Comment: ATTiny85 (with same formfactor as the 555) can be had for less than $3 a pop. Even less if you go bulk purchase. The 555 timer is $1 but that needs a few extra components like timing resistor and capacitor.

Comment: $3? Extortion! I can pick up a PIC10F200 in 8 pin DIP for £0.40, less than a 555.

Comment: A 555 astable could do this. But what time precision do you need? Would you accept differences of about 30 sec in the timing (9:30 to 10:30)? If you need **exactly** 10 minutes, it will be very difficult to tweak 2 resistors and one capacitor, it will take too much time to adjust the timing of each single board. Even if time and cost are constraints, you should go for a mc, as ATTiny. The price of the main component is not the only thing in a design's cost. The 555 IC needs extra components, the design will not be so easy, and after all you'll spend more time building, testing, adjusting.

Comment: An ATTiny10 is only $0.35 at 1 off pricing ....a 555 is typically $0.40+, and certainly more expensive with the additional components around it. Much will depend on the current limitations or interface for your output signal, but you have not explained enough to offer an opinion on that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a "precise timer", which does some of the temperature compensation for you: https://www.e2v.com/shared/content/resources/File/documents/QP_semi/NSC_LM122.pdf

Or http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/electronics/making-very-accurate-timers/  offers this schematic: [image]

Comment: +1 for an answer that provides what the OP asked for. But the number of external components indicates that the OP should go for a microcontroler.